# Load Testing in VS2010 doesn't seem to report results

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I do the following:

1. Create a Web Performance Test.  Browse around cnn.com while the recorder records the steps.
2. Create a Load Test.  Go through the wizard, attach the Web Perf Test created in the previous step.
3. Run the Load Test.  It seems to run fine with all kinds of colorful statistics and I can see requests going out via TcpView utility.  The screen looks like this, while running:

[image]

When it's all done, I get a blank screen without any results (see below).
[image]

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load Tests results need to be stored in a database. Have you configure the connection string for the sql server where the `LoadTests2010` database exists?

If not, check these links to see how to create the database and configure the connection string:

- [How to: Create a Load Test Results Repository Using SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182600.aspx)
- [How to: Select a Load Test Results Repository](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243400.aspx)